# Spring Integration and DSL upgrade - one-way 'MessageHandler' and it isn't appropriate to configure 'outputChannel' Error

Tags: spring-integration

After upgrading the above jar files, I keep running into the issue below:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: The
>   'currentComponent'
>   (org.springframework.integration.router.MethodInvokingRouter@5ddcc487)
>   is a one-way 'MessageHandler' and it isn't appropriate to configure
>   'outputChannel'. This is the end of the integration flow.     at
>   org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlowDefinition.registerOutputChannelIfCan(IntegrationFlowDefinition.java:3053)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlowDefinition.register(IntegrationFlowDefinition.java:2994)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlowDefinition.handle(IntegrationFlowDefinition.java:1167)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlowDefinition.handle(IntegrationFlowDefinition.java:987)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlowDefinition.handle(IntegrationFlowDefinition.java:964)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

Code Snippet:

```
public IntegrationFlow inBoundFlow(ConnectionFactory mqConnection)
    throws JMSException {

    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(mqConnection)
                    .configureListenerContainer(listenerContainer)
                    .destination(mqProperties.getQueue().getRequest())
                    .errorChannel(ErrorChannel())
                    .setHeaderMapper(new DefaultJmsHeaderMapper()))
            .filter(filterMessage, "filterMessage", m -> m.discardChannel(DiscardChannel()))
            .route(mqMessageRouter, "messageRouter")
            .handle(errorChannel, "handleError")
            .get();
}


@Named
public class MQErrorMessageChannel {

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = MQ_ERROR_MESSAGE_INPUT_CHANNEL, outputChannel = MQ_ERROR_MESSAGE_OUTPUT_CHANNEL)
    public Message<String> handleError(Throwable t) {
//Do Something....
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any pointer?

Answer (score 3):

The `.route(mqMessageRouter, "messageRouter")` in this form of method invocation is exactly **one-way** and you can't point anything after that in the flow.

There is no strict decision which channel will be next after router, so we can't continue the flow from there.

Just divide your flow to several and add that `.handle()` there to each particular routed flow.

Comment: You can, however, add `.defaultOutputToParentFlow()` to the router spec if you want un-routable messages to go to that `handle()` method. This was a change in 1.2 (that behavior used to be the default). See [this blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2016/09/15/java-dsl-for-spring-integration-1-2-milestone-2-is-available).

Comment: So even if the MessageRouter has this input/output channel annotations, it's configured one-way?? Refactoring might not be the our best possible solution as this template framework is used by few client apps. So need to minimize that impact.                                                                       
      public interface MQMessageRouter {

    @Router(inputChannel = ROUTER_INPUT_CHANNEL, defaultOutputChannel = ROUTER_OUTPUT_CHANNEL)
    public String messageRouter(String message, Map<String, Object> headers);
}

Comment: The problem that `IntegrationFlow` injects the `outputChannel` into the `MessageHandler` when you continue the flow definition . If it is declared as a separate component, the `IntegrationFlow` is powerless. More over you do that on the annotation level, so, there is fully no hook how to continue the flow. We decided to fix the `.route()` EIP-method to be consistent with the `AbstractMessageRouter` purpose. As Gary said: to restore the previous behavior you should use `AbstractRouterSpec..defaultOutputToParentFlow()`. But all your annotation declarations will be eliminated.