# How do I correct the "spring integration is a one-way 'MessageHandler' and it isn't appropriate to configure 'outputChannel'" exception?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have reviewed [Spring Integration and DSL upgrade - one-way 'MessageHandler' and it isn't appropriate to configure 'outputChannel' Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43375049/spring-integration-and-dsl-upgrade-one-way-messagehandler-and-it-isnt-appro) , and it looks to me like the shape of my solution is here, but the solution is expressed in a way that doesn't make sense to me.

[spring-integration parallel split-route-aggregate flow fails due to one-way MessageHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50121384/spring-integration-parallel-split-route-aggregate-flow-fails-due-to-one-way-mess) is much more understandable, but I'm not seeing where the handler method (whatever it is) is returning a void to give me this hiccup.

The exception `spring integration is a one-way 'MessageHandler' and it isn't appropriate to configure 'outputChannel'` is being thrown for the .aggregate() factory method. The queues are constructed dynamically at runtime based on metadata collected by the application.

Based on debugging into the framework, it looks like the `.routeToRecipients(r -> this.buildRecipientListRouterSpecForRules(r, rules))` clause is returning a void. Adding a `.defaultOutputToParentFlow()` to the recipientListRouter cuts out he exception, but is probably not the right solution since the flow doesn't actually start when I make this adjustment.

I'd welcome any suggestions.

Code snip:

```
        StandardIntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows
            .from(setupAdapter,
                    c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).maxMessagesPerPoll(1)))
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerExpression("xxx", "payload[0].get(\"xxx\")")
                    .headerExpression("yyy", "payload[0].get(\"yyy\")")
                    )
            .split(tableSplitter)
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerExpression("aaa", "payload[0].get(\"aaa\")")
                    .headerExpression("bbb", "payload[0].get(\"bbb\")")
                    )
            .channel(c -> c.executor(stepTaskExecutor))
            .routeToRecipients(r -> this.buildRecipientListRouterSpecForRules(r, rules))
            .aggregate()
            .handle(cleanupAdapter).get();

    return flow;



private RecipientListRouterSpec buildRecipientListRouterSpecForRules(RecipientListRouterSpec recipientListSpec,
        Collection<RuleMetadata> rules) {
    rules.forEach(
            rule -> recipientListSpec.recipientFlow(getFilterExpression(rule), f -> createFlowDefForRule(f, rule)));

    return recipientListSpec;
}
```

EDIT: Revised code for solution based on discussion below:

```
        StandardIntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows
            .from(setupAdapter,
                    c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).maxMessagesPerPoll(1)))
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerExpression("xxx", "payload[0].get(\"xxx\")")
                    .headerExpression("yyy", "payload[0].get(\"yyy\")")
                    )
            .gateway(new DirectChannel())
            .split(tableSplitter)
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerExpression("aaa", "payload[0].get(\"aaa\")")
                    .headerExpression("bbb", "payload[0].get(\"bbb\")")
                    )
            .channel(c -> c.executor(stepTaskExecutor))
            .routeToRecipients(r -> this.buildRecipientListRouterSpecForRules(r, rules).defaultOutputToParentFlow())
            .aggregate()
            .handle(cleanupAdapter).get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot continue the flow after `routeToRecipients()`. I mean your `.aggregate()` is causing that error since a `RecipientListRouter` is not an `AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler`, but just plain `AbstractMessageHandler` and it knows where to send a message after routing function only according the mapping provided for this router type.

See `defaultOutputToParentFlow()` JavaDocs for more info:

```
/**
 * Make a default output mapping of the router to the parent flow.
 * Use the next, after router, parent flow {@link MessageChannel} as a
 * {@link AbstractMessageRouter#setDefaultOutputChannel(MessageChannel)} of this router.
 * @return the router spec.
 */
public S defaultOutputToParentFlow() {
```

So, it would continue your flow only if it doesn't match the recipients mapping.
The `ignoreSendFailures(true)` has to be set, too, to let it to not fail with an error, but rather fallback to this default output.

Comment: Thank you @Artem Bilan. Reading between the lines here, I'm missing some key concept embodied in the classes, and using a completely incorrect mechanism for splitting to subflows then later rejoining to the main flow. Is this corrrect?

Comment: You need to think about a gateway on top of recipient list router . Then an aggregator to re-join results from those recipient sub-flows. And only after that you can send reply back to the gateway and continue the main flow.

Comment: Does each recipient flow requires its own gateway? Or is a single gateway referenced by all recipient flows required?

Comment: Single gateway from the main flow to wait for aggregated reply

Comment: I think I understand better. I have updated my code snip as I understand it now, and am reading "Pro Spring Integration" to try to further my understanding.

Comment: The flow constructs now, but does not appear to start.

The thread appears to be claimed from the thread pool when flow.start() is invoked, but a breakpoint set in JdbcPollingChannelAdapter.doPoll() is never hit. Logs show nothing from org.springframework.integration

Comment: I think we need to see your new flow configuration , but that’s probably need to be done in the separate SO thread

Comment: A simplified flow for the :won't start" has been posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65499125/sprint-integration-flow-wont-start

Comment: Is there a good primer for the concepts here? All of the documentation and books I have found on Spring Integration start with the assumption that you already know how these components tie together and when to use them. Monkeying it until it works is not a viable solution, nor is harassing you on SO every time I hit a minor NOOB roadblock.

Comment: Right. You need to know what is EIP, first of all, to understand what is a message, endpoint and channel between them. Then you need to learn what is Spring and its application context with beans and some infrastructure . And only after that you come to Spring Integration with its concept to implement EIP on top of Spring Framework. If you miss some pieces (as we all do), then you go try-n-fall road until you got used to everything you need from these tools. I don’t see nothing problematic in the asking questions. This is really was the way for me when I learned Java 20 years ago...

Comment: Sadly, I have a very short timeframe for this. The Java is super easy, it's the rest of this particular stack that is proving hard to wrap my head around.

Comment: Ok. So, do your best with whatever you know already introducing Spring features gradually as you learn them.

Comment: (Venting) Your help throughout has been valuable, but we are missing something very core that you are taking for granted. After almost a year and multiple SO questions, we have achieved nothing and are at the end of our rope. Every time we think we have made a step forward, we appear to be further from a solution. Constructing and debugging this dead simple flow has been a year long project for several experienced java programmers, with no solution. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: The recipient list router (or better to say any router) is a one-way component in the flow. It cannot answer directly to the next channel, just because it is multi-channel (or dynamic) output component. See its pattern: https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/MessageRouter.html. The flow is linear, and cannot have several channels to branch. That's how it happens the router can be only in the end of flow. We probably need to state that clearly in the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#router

Comment: That may help, and works for our flow. After routing, its jdbc fetch -> jdbc CRUD -> jdbc cleanup -> done.  I noticed in your examples you have bridge() at the end of every subflow. When we use bridge(), the component complains it has no reply channel. Is there a clean way to say "this is the end of the flow"? Would giving hte null channel as the reply channel do the trick?

Comment: Yes, Will do. That's one of those corner-cases when `nullChannel` is useful: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#channel-special-channels