# Sprint integration flow won't start

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

This looks like a beginner question to me.

For the sake of easy reproduction, I have stripped out virtually all of my logic from this flow. The reason it looks like it does nothing is because it, quite literally, fetches data from a JDBC endpoint and does exactly nothing.

```
        setupAdapter = new JdbcPollingChannelAdapter(dbprx.getDatasource(), sql.getSql());
        setupAdapter.setRowMapper(rowMapper);

        StandardIntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows
            .from(setupAdapter,
                    c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).maxMessagesPerPoll(1)))
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerExpression("aaa", "payload[0].get(\"aaa\")")
                    .headerExpression("bbb", "payload[0].get(\"bbb\")")
                    )
            .get();

    flow.start();
```

I expect the flow to be constructed and fire when (or shortly after) the is started. Instead, the flow is constructed and nothing happens. I have set a breakpoint at the beginning of JDBCPollingChannelAdapter.doPoll() , which should be tripped once per second if all is running correctly.

Any and all suggestions will be welcome.

---

Edit: corrected code snip, showing registration of hte flow in the spring context before attempting to start (note this is not a complete example, it simply demonstrates the partial correction in the context for my process dynamically creating flows based on my own dynamic sources). A more common solution is to create the flows statically with @Bean annotations:

```
        setupAdapter = new JdbcPollingChannelAdapter(dbprx.getDatasource(), sql.getSql());
        setupAdapter.setRowMapper(rowMapper);

        StandardIntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows
            .from(setupAdapter,
                    c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).maxMessagesPerPoll(1)))
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerExpression("aaa", "payload[0].get(\"aaa\")")
                    .headerExpression("bbb", "payload[0].get(\"bbb\")")
                    )
            .get();

    flowContext.registration(flow).id(this.getId().toString()).register();

    flow.start();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the main point of Spring - Inversion of Control container.

The `IntegrationFlow` is nothing by itself. It has to be added to the `ApplicationContext` as a bean, then this context with Spring container and its `BeanFactory` will do everything we want from that `IntegrationFlow` abstraction. At the moment you just do all the `new` stuff by yourself and you don't wire it up with any `AplicationContext`.

I'm not sure what is your logic, but you need to consider to make this flow as a `@Bean` in some `@Configuration` class. The application context will parse this `IntegraitonFlow`, create required beans, autowire them with others (if required) and start the flow for us. Automaticaly.

Please, learn what is Spring application context: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#spring-core

And how to make an `IntegrationFlow` as a bean: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl

Comment: This makes sense.  It is one thing to be able to walk through the application context and understand that technically it is a wrapper around a set of hash maps, and another to think in terms of the underlying design intent.

Comment: We can close this thread.  Once you pointed point out that I didn't have Spring components in the Spring application context it was sufficient. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Good, so time to accept the answer and let other know that there is a solution for them, too, in this thread . At the same time I’ll go and improve that `IntegrationFlow.start()` to fail with error that it must be declared as a bean in the application contex